# Integrate Redux Framework with bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am developing my first theme and I have been using the Bootstrap framework for the layout.  I have done some searching in trying to find tutorials on how to integrate them both, but have come up empty handed.

Is there anyone that can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

So... that's a loaded question.

Use the Redux Builder (http://build.reduxframework.com). Then export out an _s theme, which will get you the base stuff for a theme.

Then look up tutorials for _s (underscores) and boostrap. And you'll be good to go.

Or use http://shoestrap.org/, http://danvswild.com/brew/, or something similar.

Good luck!